# --peerAddresses in Hyperledger Fabric v1.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I was going through the documentation of Hyperledger Fabric v1.2. There was an invoke command and it seems like it is update in v1.2. I found a parameter `--peerAddresses` in

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
```

Anyone know what this parameter does? There was nothing mentioned in the official documentation about this paramete.

You can find the documentation here http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html

Topic: Build your first network
Command: Invoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--peerAddresses` introduced in Fabric v1.2 is used to specify a particular peer for endorsement.

**Note:** This parameter will not override the endorsement policy specified during chaincode instantiation.